# Rails paperclip file upload field not working - multiple choice image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am having some problem with uploading images with my file upload field. It does not upload anything. But the image url field works. I think it have some to do with my model.

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @virksomhed] do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :link_attributes do |d| %>
    <% end %>
<%= f.simple_fields_for :photo_attributes do |d| %>
    <%= d.label :image, :label => 'Upload logo', :required => false  %>
    <%= d.file_field :image, :label => 'Image, :required => false', :style => 'margin-bottom:2px'  %>
    <%= d.input :image_url, :label => 'Billed URL', :required => false %>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit "Opret virksomhed" %>
<% end %>
```

My Photo model:

```
require 'open-uri'

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :virksomhed
  attr_accessor :image_url

  has_attached_file :image,
                  :url  => "/public/images/billeder/photo/:id/:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:basename.:extension"

  before_validation :download_remote_image, :if => :image_url_provided?


private

  def image_url_provided?
    !self.image_url.blank?
  end

  def download_remote_image
    self.image = do_download_remote_image
    self.image_remote_url = image_url
  end

  def do_download_remote_image
    io = open(URI.parse(image_url))
    def io.original_filename; base_uri.path.split('/').last; end
    io.original_filename.blank? ? nil : io
  rescue # catch url errors with validations instead of exceptions (Errno::ENOENT, OpenURI::HTTPError, etc...)
  end

end
```

My virksomhed model:

```
class Virksomhed < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :photo

accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo
end
```

Comment: Does this fail for both local and remote files?

Comment: edit!: Only the the remote files works (with the image url field) I think it does have some to do with the valdiation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :photo_attributes, :html => { :multipart => true } do |d| %>
```

And also for my form I added `, :html => { :multipart => true }`

It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although photo_attributes is used in the background, all the examples I can find seem to suggest that you should be using this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :photo do |d| %>
```

Comment: Then the input fields disappears.